# Where is this extra height coming from?

Tags: css

i've been using CSS every working day for years now but I totally lost with this one.

On [this page in development](http://www.ballewsawandtool.com/dev/brands/) there is a huge amount of extra height but i have no idea where it is coming from.

Can anyone see what is going on? thanks

Comment: What is `extra height`? Where is it on your page?

Comment: It appears to be related to wrapping the contents of `section.entry` in `<pre>` tags. Are they there for a reason?

Comment: sorry if this question was 'off-topic' due to being not specific enough. The page was 5 times the height it needed to be due in the end to things being wrapped in a stow away <pre> tag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the `pre` tag that you have wrapped around the lists. It will cause every line break in the markup to show up as spacing between the elements.

I tested by removing the `pre` tag, and that removes the extra spacing, but it also makes the element use their default font and size. Set the `font-family` and `font-size` of the content to get the font and size that you want, instead of the `pre` tag.

Comment: Damn you and your faster typing...

Comment: Nimble fingers, sir :D

Comment: Awesome thanks Guffa, you were right! somehow there was some <pre> code left on that page. I removed it and all is well now, thanks so much :)

Answer (score 0):

Each element inside the `section.entry` is separated with **three `<font>` tags**. They're empty but their default height is `17px`.

### Solution:

Remove the `font` tags.

Comment: I don't see any `<font>` tags in the source. Am I missing something?

Comment: They're generated by javascript. Anyways, Guffa's answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The `<pre>` tag is used for adding pre-formatted text to the page. Therefore, everything inside the tag is rendered exactly as it is in the source, including whitespace:

[`<pre>` - HTML | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre)

If you're not using properly pre-formatted text (as you're obviously not in this case), you should remove the `<pre>` tag and use CSS to format your font appropriately.